# can not connect machine learning to mobile app

Tags: machine-learning, flutter, mobile

I have a python machine learning code and a flutter mobile application code. is there a way to connect between both of them? Also, is there a library in flutter which can apply the concepts of machine learning/ neural networks on texts?
Moreover, what is the best practise/ tools/ platforms to develop a mobile application based on machine learning?

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no way to run Python code within a flutter app. So you'll probably need to interface the two with an API. However, this is gonna require a larger codebase and you'll have to pay for server bandwidth. So it's much more easy to just build out your ML functionality within Flutter.

**If you insist on going with Python for your ML:**

You'll need to build a RESTful API.

Here are some resources for you to get started on that path.

(1) https://www.codementor.io/sagaragarwal94/building-a-basic-restful-api-in-python-58k02xsiq

(2) https://realpython.com/flask-connexion-rest-api/

There are a lot of different frameworks you can do this with, see (2).

Once you get that up and running here's a tutorial for importing that data into your Flutter app:

(3) https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python_data_science/python_processing_json_data.htm

**If you want to build your ML inside of Flutter**

This depends on your use case, but consider checking out (4) and using the MLKit for Firebase.

(4) http://flutterdevs.com/blog/machine-learning-in-flutter/

If you want to get into a little bit more into the weeds or you have a more specific use case, see (5).

(5) https://flutterawesome.com/a-machine-learning-app-for-an-age-old-debate/

***Good luck!***